# Convert JSON data to geometry

Tags: convert, json, format

I have been given some spatial data in a table in a format that I have never come across before and would like to convert it to geometry.

How can I convert to geometry? I could use 'text to columns' function in Excel to split the coordinates up then merge them back together to WKT format, but I was hoping there might be a faster way to convert using QGIS or ArcGIS Pro. I don't know how to write Python scripts, so looking for a plugin or tool or similar.

Here are two sample rows from the 'Location' field of the table:

```
{"poly":[],"lat":-43.90554038530789,"lng":171.7366969600843,"place_id":"ChIJO_-_46y7LW0RIiYCTH3DgpE","region":"Canterbury","district":"Ashburton District"}

{"id":"","place_id":"ChIJVebsRr8YbW0Ru9B5-9kqAaA","lat":-37.783528339369091,"lng":175.29208721117561,"poly":[{"lat":-37.784817198087467,"lng":175.29316009478157},{"lat":-37.784240611203458,"lng":175.29101432756966},{"lat":-37.783392681143624,"lng":175.29178680376594},{"lat":-37.782239480650716,"lng":175.2919584651429},{"lat":-37.783731854334924,"lng":175.29303134874885}],"region":"Waikato","district":"Hamilton City"}
```

Comment: that is json format

Comment: There are an infinite number of UTF-8 formats available. The format is far less important than how it can be processed.  You should [Edit] the Question to ask about that.

Comment: Place ID relates to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-id most likely.

Comment: It's quite wasteful to parse JSON with Excel when you have Python (which can trivially read JSON) available. Unfortunately, you've got a number of questions and platforms in this Question, which violates the One question per Question policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to try out some python.  This script will convert your json columns into 2 new columns - 1 for the centroid wkt (the lat/lng part of the json) and 1 column for the poly wkt.  It assumes your input csv has 2 columns [id,geom] - edit the csv or script to match your data.  Also, if you want to extract other parts of the json, you can use the appropriate key (i.e. `j["place_id"]`):

```
#import modules
import csv
import json

#input and output file paths
filename = r"E:\test.csv"
outfile = r"E:\test_mod.csv"


#open the input and output files
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvFile, open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as newfile:
    #initialize a reader for the input csv
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    next(reader, None) #skip the header row
    #initialize a writer for the output csv
    writer = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    #create and write a new header for the output csv
    newheader = ['id','centroid','polygon']
    writer.writerow(newheader)
    #loop through the rows - each row will be a list of cells
    for row in reader:
        #row[0] is id column, row[1] is geom column
        #read the json data into a python dictionary
        j = json.loads(row[1])
        #Check that lat and lng exist in the json
        if j.get('lng') and j.get('lat'):
            #create the centroid wkt
            centroid = 'POINT (' + str(j['lng']) + ' ' + str(j['lat']) + ')'
        else:
            centroid = ''
        #check that poly exists in the json
        g = j.get("poly")
        if g and len(g) > 0:
            #format coords for wkt
            coords = [str(x['lng']) + ' ' + str(x['lat']) for x in g]
            #create the polygon wkt
            polygon = 'POLYGON ((' + (', ').join(coords) + '))'
        else:
            polygon = ''
        print(centroid)
        print(polygon)
        #create the new output row and write it to output csv
        newrow = [row[0],centroid,polygon]
        writer.writerow(newrow)
```

sample output:

| id | centroid | polygon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POINT (171.7366969600843 -43.90554038530789) |  |
| 2 | POINT (175.2920872111756 -37.78352833936909) | POLYGON ((175.29316009478157 -37.78481719808747, 175.29101432756966 -37.78424061120346, 175.29178680376594 -37.783392681143624, 175.2919584651429 -37.782239480650716, 175.29303134874885 -37.783731854334924)) |

Comment: Looks ideal, but I am getting this error when I run the script: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [7]:
Line 28:    g = j["poly"]

KeyError: 'poly' .                                                    It sounds like I need to add "poly' to a dictionary but I have no idea how to do that in the context of this script. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you see if any of the json is missing `poly`?  Actually, I will edit the script to handle that.  I think that is probably the issue.

Comment: Also, for some background on the script - the json module is doing the work of converting the json data into a python dictionary.  It's probably working correctly, but the json data is missing keys for some rows.  If you try to get a key from the dictionary that doesn't exist, you'll get a key error.

Comment: I edited the script to check that the keys exist in the json before trying to use them.

Comment: I just had to add a bit to the 'open' function (something to do with encoding): "with open(filename, 'r', newline='',encoding='utf-8')"   and it worked like a charm!